# migrating comments on disqus from one blog engine to other

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

Currently i have started using [Nick Jhonshon's bloggart](https://github.com/Arachnid/bloggart) on appengine, later i do want to undergo the exercise of writing a blog engine for myself. Just one `query`, will i be able to export `disqus` `comments` and `reactions` when i migrate from the current blog engine (bloggart on appengine) to my own blog engine (most probably in django) running somewhere on `ec2`/`vps`??

Comment: Disqus comments are linked to page ID which is URL or you can provide that ID manually. So you should maintain your URLs or IDs intact when moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Your comments aren't stored by the app, they're stored by disqus. As long as you keep the URLs the same - or tell Disqus what the old URL was - your comments will continue to show up.